# Anthy how to find out what to type for a specific kana?

Tags: 16.04, input-language

On Unity Ubuntu 16.04 I want to type  づ  instead of ず they are both pronounced as "zu" in romanji and I do not know how to type the different variation.

Do you know what to type in order to display the korrect kana?

Comment: Nowadays I am using Mozc, not Anthy, but maybe the keyboard entry is the same. In Japanese IME or WP applications I have used before, you would enter "dzu", but in mozc it is "du". Doesn't make a lot of sense but that's romaji for you. Give it a try.

Comment: Yeap that was the kana. following the answer I found it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what to type BUT you can find out especially for those using `Greek` as system language via folowing theese steps (for those using `English` one the images are pretty much self-explanatory anthy settings are in English as well):

1. Go to input method settings:

[image: Selecting Imput method changes]

2. On the window opened Select "Anthy" and click on the icon shown in the image bellow:

[image: Selecting anthy configuration]

3. On the anthy settings window select "Typing Method":
   [image: Window on selection what tab to select what romanji to type]
4. Then select the button next to `Πίνακας Πλήκτρων Ρομάτζι` (for English System Language users look at the image):
   [image: Select the Romanji list]
5. Afterwards you can search got your kana you need to type and look the correct english keyboard combination as the following image shows:

[image: Key combinations to type the correct hiragana]